# What computer games provide practice?

Tags: games

What On-line, for download or for purchase software-based games provide fun language practice for learners of Chinese? What level of learner are they best suited for? What platform do they run on?

Comment: Do you have an iOS device? If you do I'd have some further recommendations.

Comment: No, I don't, but such answers might be useful to other users, so go ahead and post them.

Comment: Right now, this is pretty open-ended... Why not describe *your* platform, *your* level, and the other specifics of your situation and let folks give you advice that pertains to it?

Answer (score 2):

One game I suggest you check out is [Enter Zon](http://enterzon.com/) - an MMORPG specifically for learning Mandarin.

Essentially you run around in a game environment and have all sorts of dialogues about different things, with the end goal of improving your Mandarin. It's pretty neat.

Comment: This no longer seems available.